# MonoMac NSWorkspace.RecycleUrls vs. recycleURLs:completionHandler

Tags: c#, cocoa, monomac

According to [the MonoMac documentation](http://docs.go-mono.com/index.aspx?link=M%3AMonoMac.AppKit.NSWorkspace.RecycleUrls%28MonoMac.Foundation.NSDictionary%2CMonoMac.AppKit.NSWorkspaceUrlHandler%29) the signature for `NSWorkspace.RecycleUrls` is:

```
[MonoMac.Foundation.Export("recycleURLs:completionHandler:")]
public virtual void RecycleUrls (MonoMac.Foundation.NSDictionary urls, NSWorkspaceUrlHandler completionHandler)
```

According to [Apple's documentation for `NSWorkspace`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWorkspace_Class/Reference/Reference.html) the signature for `recycleURLs:completionHandler` is:

```
- (void)recycleURLs:(NSArray *)URLs completionHandler:(void (^)(NSDictionary *newURLs, NSError *error))handler
```

I have an array of URLs that I want recycled.

Here I'm stumped - the Apple documentation says the first parameter is an `NSArray` but MonoMac wants an `NSDictionary`. All the functions to construct an `NSDictionary` want keys *and* values (unsurprisingly) whereas I only have *values*.

Is there anything to be done other than taking MonoMac's implementation of `RecycleUrls` (reproduced below) and rewriting it to use an `NSArray`?

```
[Export("recycleURLs:completionHandler:")]
public unsafe virtual void RecycleUrls(NSDictionary urls, NSWorkspaceUrlHandler completionHandler)
{
    if (urls == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("urls");
    }
    if (completionHandler == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("completionHandler");
    }
    BlockLiteral blockLiteral = default(BlockLiteral);
    blockLiteral.SetupBlock(NSWorkspace.static_InnerNSWorkspaceUrlHandler, completionHandler);
    if (this.IsDirectBinding)
    {
        Messaging.void_objc_msgSend_IntPtr_IntPtr(base.Handle, NSWorkspace.selRecycleURLsCompletionHandler_, urls.Handle, (IntPtr)((void*)(&blockLiteral)));
    }
    else
    {
        Messaging.void_objc_msgSendSuper_IntPtr_IntPtr(base.SuperHandle, NSWorkspace.selRecycleURLsCompletionHandler_, urls.Handle, (IntPtr)((void*)(&blockLiteral)));
    }
    blockLiteral.CleanupBlock();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mono's binding was incorrect, I changed both `NSWorkspace.RecycleUrls()` and `NSWorkspace.DuplicateUrls()` to take an `NSArray` instead of `NSDictionary`, [monomac commit b1eda57](https://github.com/mono/monomac/commit/b1eda576d8f36cd8ae65fce8d18ff0697cb95a5e).

This is the generated code:

```
    [Export ("recycleURLs:completionHandler:")]
    public unsafe virtual void RecycleUrls (NSArray urls, NSWorkspaceUrlHandler completionHandler)
    {
        if (urls == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException ("urls");
        if (completionHandler == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException ("completionHandler");
        BlockLiteral *block_ptr_completionHandler;
        BlockLiteral block_completionHandler;
        block_completionHandler = new BlockLiteral ();
        block_ptr_completionHandler = &block_completionHandler;
        block_completionHandler.SetupBlock (static_InnerNSWorkspaceUrlHandler, completionHandler);

        if (IsDirectBinding) {
            MonoMac.ObjCRuntime.Messaging.void_objc_msgSend_IntPtr_IntPtr (this.Handle, selRecycleURLsCompletionHandler_, urls.Handle, (IntPtr) block_ptr_completionHandler);
        } else {
            MonoMac.ObjCRuntime.Messaging.void_objc_msgSendSuper_IntPtr_IntPtr (this.SuperHandle, selRecycleURLsCompletionHandler_, urls.Handle, (IntPtr) block_ptr_completionHandler);
        }
        block_ptr_completionHandler->CleanupBlock ();

    }

    [Export ("duplicateURLs:completionHandler:")]
    public unsafe virtual void DuplicateUrls (NSArray urls, NSWorkspaceUrlHandler completionHandler)
    {
        if (urls == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException ("urls");
        if (completionHandler == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException ("completionHandler");
        BlockLiteral *block_ptr_completionHandler;
        BlockLiteral block_completionHandler;
        block_completionHandler = new BlockLiteral ();
        block_ptr_completionHandler = &block_completionHandler;
        block_completionHandler.SetupBlock (static_InnerNSWorkspaceUrlHandler, completionHandler);

        if (IsDirectBinding) {
            MonoMac.ObjCRuntime.Messaging.void_objc_msgSend_IntPtr_IntPtr (this.Handle, selDuplicateURLsCompletionHandler_, urls.Handle, (IntPtr) block_ptr_completionHandler);
        } else {
            MonoMac.ObjCRuntime.Messaging.void_objc_msgSendSuper_IntPtr_IntPtr (this.SuperHandle, selDuplicateURLsCompletionHandler_, urls.Handle, (IntPtr) block_ptr_completionHandler);
        }
        block_ptr_completionHandler->CleanupBlock ();

    }
```

Quick test:

```
    void TestUrls ()
    {
        var path = Path.GetTempFileName ();
        Console.WriteLine ("TEST: {0} {1}", path, File.Exists (path));

        var array = new NSMutableArray ();
        var url = new NSUrl ("file://" + path);
        array.Add (url);

        var workspace = NSWorkspace.SharedWorkspace;
        workspace.DuplicateUrls (array, (urls, error) => {
            Console.WriteLine ("DUPLICATED: {0} {1}", urls, error);
            array.Add (urls.Values [0]);

            workspace.RecycleUrls (array, (urls2, error2) => {
                Console.WriteLine ("RECYCLED: {0} {1} {2}",
                                   urls2, error2, File.Exists (path));
            });
        });
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the investigation.

Comment: I believe that `RecycleUrls` is asynchronous, what's the purpose of calling `CleanupBlock` before the completion block is called? I can see the implementation calls some sort of resource deallocation (`GCHandle.FromIntPtr(...).Free();`), but I would expect resource freeing to occur *after* the function completed.

Comment: Oh, good point!  Didn't even look at that piece of auto-generated code.  Looks like we may have to do something in the generator about this, I'll have a look.